# What does the term "embodiment" mean in the software patent?

Tags: embodiments

**What does the term "embodiment" mean in the software patent?**

I often see this term embodiment in the patent documents (i.e. 1st embodiment, 2nd embodiment). Dictionary meaning of the term [embodiment](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/embodiment) is,

> someone or something that represents a quality or an idea exactly:

This meaning seems very vague and abstract to me. Could anyone clarify what does the term 'embodiment' mean in a patent document? Any background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means an example of something that includes the claimed invention. An embodiment is a concrete thing or process that practices the more abstract “invention-as-claimed”. Implementation is close to the meaning of embodiment.

The invention itself is defined by one or more numbered claims. Claims  are written in a way to apply to more than a single embodiment.

If a claim says “a device for electrical connection comprising two sets of physically complimentary electrical contacts in housings, the housings operatively retained together magnetically without requiring  mutual friction to maintain a physically secure electrical connection”, then an embodiment would be Apple’s [MagSafe](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC461LL/A/apple-60w-magsafe-power-adapter-for-macbook-and-13-inch-macbook-pro) power connectors for its laptops. An alternative embodiment might be housings retained electromagnetically rather than by permanent magnets or be large enough to operate as part of a golf cart charging system rather than a laptop.

This example is for a device. For software it would be analogous with a general claim and usually one or more specific embodiments. *Very* roughly speaking, a claim would define a general principle and an embodiment would be a specific implementation using that principle.

Comment: Thanks you so much. It helps.